# JavaMail Problema de envio al usar un correo webmail

Tags: java, netbeans

estoy con un problema al enviar un correo desde aplicación hecha en Java  (netbeans). El problema es que quiero usar un correo "webmail" en vez de gmail (donde sí funciona) el tema es que al hacer las modificaciones correspondiente, el frame se congela y no puedo hacer nada mas, por bastante tiempo.
Les comparto el codigo:

```
public void SendMail() {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.smartsim.cl");  // modificar por smtp.gmail.com
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); // puerto 587
    //props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session;
            session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                            //return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                        }
                    });

    try {

          // Define message
          MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
          message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
          message.setSubject("Recuperacion de Contraseña");
          message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("prueba@smartsim.cl"));
          message.setText("Nombre Usuario: " +Usuario+" " +"Email de contacto: "+ Mensaje);

          // Envia el mensaje
          Transport.send(message);

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Mensaje Enviado Correctamente");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(Enviarcorreo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
        }
```

Comment: Normalmente esas cuentas de webmail necesitan configuraciones mas simples que las del gmail, intenta por un lado usando el puerto 25, sin nada de tls/ssl y no olvidar cambiar el nombre o ip del servidor de correo

Comment: vale, lo he intentando, de hecho el webmail, da los parametros para hacer este tipo de conexiones, por lo que he hecho los cambios correspondientes y nada aún

Comment: por que no compartes tu código con los ajustes que dices haber hecho, es difícil imaginar solo a partir de tus comentarios lo que puede estar mal. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este metodo. Haz las modificaciones oportunas (servidor smtp, cuenta, pass, cuerpo del mensaje...)

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

```
public void enviarMail(String destinatario, String asunto, String cuerpo) {

    String remitente = "tu cuenta"; // Para la dirección nomcuenta@gmail.com

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); // El servidor SMTP de Google
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", remitente);
    props.put("mail.smtp.clave", "tu pass"); // Pass cuenta
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); // Autenticación mediante usuario y pass
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // Conexió segura al servidor
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); // Puerto SMTP seguro de Google

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(remitente));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, destinatario);
        message.setSubject(asunto);
        //message.setText(cuerpo);
        message.setContent(cuerpo, "text");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", remitente, "tu pass");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    } catch (MessagingException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: De hecho ya habia intentado ese modo con Gmail y funcionó a la perfección, pero al usar los parametros de Webmail... nada, ha estado mas de 45min en ejecución, congelado, y sigue estando así